# How can I get to installed app list on iPhone device?

Tags: iphone

I'm new for iPhone dev.
I got a question for development of iPhone app.
Is it possible to get to installed app list on iPhone device?
thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Connect you device in your system, use following command in terminal

ideviceinstaller -l

you will get the list of app installed in you iphone device

note: you should install ideviceinstaller package in your system

Answer (score 3):

Apps on a non-jailbroken phone are "sandboxed" so you don't get unfettered access to the filesystem. This means that you can't directly see what other applications are available. Also, just because they're installed does not mean that they are available to the current user. For instance, Safari is always installed but can be disabled in the Parental Controls settings.

The best supported (i.e., in a way that Apple will approve of) way of of doing it might be to check the available URL schemes. For example, if "http:" is supported then Safari is usable; if "mailto:" is available then Mail is usable, etc. Of course, not all applications have URL schemes.

Comment: I've just noticed that the new BUMP iPhone app has a section in which you can browse your own installed apps. It's not the entire list but still a part of it. Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to grab yourself a copy of the Apple [iPhone Configuration Utility](http://support.apple.com/downloads/iPhone_Configuration_Utility_2_0_for_Mac_OS_X), which will give you a list of installed apps, plus access to the console output from the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Grab the iPhone configuration tool and run this regex on the Export:

```
[ \t]+<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>[ \t\r\n]+<string>([A-Za-z \&\-,\!]+)</string>
```

You can then grab the list of apps nice and easily.

Answer (score -2):

Here's what I did, without jailbreaking. (yes it sounds stupid, but it was simple and worked well for me)

- Go to your home screen.
- Hit the lock button + home button (takes a screenshot)
- Open you folders and do the same.
- Do the same for any other pages you have.
- All the names of installed apps are now in your pictures folder, just copy the pictures to your computer, and finished!